# Leonhard Euler's Books in the Analysis and Algebra

Tags: analysis, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am an aspiring mathematician who is deeply interested in the analysis, topology, and their applications to the microbiology.   Recently, I started to become very curious about why concepts and theorems in the real analysis and topics come as they are; the legendary books in topology like Engelking and Kelley have been guiding me to answer the questions such as "Why do we care?" or "What motivates such theorems, definitions, axioms?", but I was not able to answer such questions from the analysis books like Rudin, which actually resulted in shallow understanding of the analysis (somehow I forced myself to memorize the contents from Rudin)...That is a reason why I decided to read some analysis books over the rest of this Summer, such as Euler, Hairer/Wanner, Bressoud, to understand the historical foundations of the concepts in basic analysis.

I am particularly interested in Euler's books:  "Introduction to Analysis of the Infinite, I-II", "Foundations of Differential Calculus", and "Elements of Algebra".  For those who have experience or read those books, could you tell me how they inspired or benefited you?  Also, are those books fairly independent of each other?   Are they better than books like Hairer/Wanner to learn about the historical background of real analysis?

I also might try Gauss' Disquisitiones Arithmaticae to learn about the number theory in details.

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend Ifinite Series by Knopp, it's 100 years old but a timeless classic I was led to by Don Zagier.  I don't like how Knopp constructs the real numbers but once you get over that, you just have to be patient and solider through it, it's a truly enlightening treatment of the subject.  As for Gauss, I think you benefit more from more modern treatments of the subject.

Comment: I would really recommend looking at analysis after the definition of a limit became formal.  Looking to results before that time and some of the proofs you find won't be considered rigorous by today's standards.  I would recommend "Introductory Real Analysis" by Kolmogorov and Fomin.  It will introduce you to a plethora of concepts, and the dover edition is extremely cheap (I believe it's less than $15 on amazon).

Comment: @Aweygan  Thanks for your advice.  Actually, my plan is to read Kolmogorov/Fomin soon, but I think it would also be beneficial for me to learn historical contexts of the real analysis as I like keep questioning myself the origins and usefulness of the theorems and concepts.

Comment: Rudin is extremely unfriendly for beginners. I would recommend Royden / Apostol / Bartle for analysis. Any of these three would be better than Rudin.

Comment: @GregoryGrant  I should try Knopp too....He does have two similar books in the series....Are they basically the same?

Comment: @yoyostein  I actually read Rudin....but realized that I did not understand as much as I expected.

Comment: @MathWanderer Same here, I did not get Rudin on my first reading. Rudin is good as a reference book after one has learnt the material, not for those who are learning it for the first time.

Comment: @yoyostein I am actually reading Korner now (very great book!), but I would like to know the historical background of real analysis, such as from Euler or Hairer.

Comment: @MathWanderer cool. I just looked up Korner. He seems to be a humorous writer.

Comment: I would recommend the very clear "Analysis by Its History" by Ernst Hairer and Gerhard Wanner (Springer).

Comment: It's called Theory and Applications of Infinite Series, by Knopp (not Knapp)

Comment: Some parts of Euler "Opera" are still very readable, but it's better to begin by other authors, especialy when they re-write and extend works of this genius. I warmly recommend a true marvel: Hardy and Wright's "An introduction to the Theory of numbers" (first ed. 1938 !) which is also a book using analysis, which you can find [on line](matematica.cubaeduca.cu/medias/pdf/842.pdf). Look for example at their Chapter XIX.

Comment: Great as Euler was, I strongly recommend against reading those books. Books written by great mathematicians of the past will be difficult for us to understand, because of the messy notation. Often a lot of struggle is done to say something very simple today. Also, keep in mind that analysis wasn't made rigorous when Euler was alive. That happened with Cauchy, Weirstrass, Dedekind, Peano, etc. Ethan Blouch's book is really good, as is Terrance Tao's. Both have deep explanations, at least for my level. Stein has a great series on analysis, but I'm not sure it contains what you want.

Comment: @user230452  I read some chapters in Bloch and Tao, but I dislike Bloch and I found Landau to be better than Tao....My plan is to study some historical books before jumping into real analysis like Stein and Kolmogorov/Fomin.  So is there no truly useful insightful in books written by Euler, Gauss, etc.?

Comment: @MathWanderer I recommend the following book to you - "Analysis by its History" - Hairer and Wanner, and strongly discourage you from wasting your time by reading books by Euler and Gauss, as most energy would be spent in deciphering the language (I don't think they wrote in English), the old grammar of the language and the notation of the day instead of understand the material itself (which requires effort even with clear exposition). Moreover, analysis wasn't really formalized until Cauchy, Weirstrass, etc.

Comment: A lighter popular book I enjoyed was William Dunham's "Calculus Gallery".

Answer (score 3):

I love this phrase from the famous mathematician, Paul Halmos, given at the beggining of a series of lectures on linear operators:

> *"A thing that happens very often in mathematics is that you start with something concrete(...), and out of this concrete concept grows an abstract axiomatic notion (...), then you suddenly discover, with a pleasant surprise (only it shouldn't have been all that surprising), that every one of these abstract objects has a concrete representation by one of those things that you started out with."*

My recommendation for a general historical overview on mathematics is **Stillwell's "Mathematics and it's history"**. This is not a theorem-proof kind of book, since he is not interested in developing theory, but gives many examples of concrete objects, abstract notions and theorems that have been studied by mathematicians throughout history, which at later stage became the prototypical examples of more general theories. Also, he is much more focused on the mathematics than on the biographies of the great mathematicians. Another nice thing is that he uses modern notation, so you don't have to struggle to decipher what he means.

I find this last point very important; I do not doubt there is much to be gained by reading the old texts, and by any means I'm not arguing not to do so. Reading Euclid or Newton's arguments makes you appreciate the benefits of our modern notation and rigour, for example. Nevertheless, I would recommend modern books focused on the historical development of the theory.

**P.S.** Halmos lectures can be seen here: http://av.cah.utexas.edu/index.php/Category:P.R._Halmos_Lecture_Film_Series

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I remember Stilwell's books to be excellent, but I found his history books to be not as exciting as Hairer/Wanner (focused in the analysis, of course).